# How to create new objects from fetched results?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, fetch

I am trying to use fetched results(some text) to create a new objects, this is my code so far

```
     <script>

    class Student {
   
   constructor(name, address, phone, course) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.course = course;
   }
   getInfo() {
        return "Ime: " + this.name + "\n" +
"Adresa: " + this.address + "\n" +
"Telefon: " + this.phone + "\n" +
"Kurs: " + this.course;
    }  }
    
   

  async function getData () {
      const response = await fetch('https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt');
      const students = await response.text();
      
      return students;
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , async ()=>{

 

   try {
       students = await getData();
   }catch(e) {
       console.log("Error!");
       console.log(e);
   }

   

console.log(students);


  })


    </script>
```

> ```
> > *Fetch text is something like this:*
> >     Ebonie 
> >     7175 Muland Street
> >     8343242
> >     Math
> >     Keenan 
> >     2 Elm Lane
> >     832432
> >     History***
> ```

```
As a result i need to get:
var student1 = new Student(" Ebonie "," 7175 Muland Street",8343242,"Math");
var student2 = new Student("  Keenan  ","  2 Elm Lane",832432, History");
......
```

I guess i need to loop through text and then somehow to store text into new objects.
Output should be:
name: Ebonie
address: 7175 Muland Street
phone: 8343242
course: math

Comment: Please fix the format (there's text that does not belong into a code block), fix the indentation and explain your _"guess i need to loop"_ and the _"...to use split method to parse result"_

Comment: after try catch I believe there is an extra `}`. what does `getData()` currently return?

Comment: I will fix it,getData returns text" Ebonie ,7175 Muland Street, 8343242, Math, Keenan.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 class Student {

   constructor(name, address, phone, course) {
     this.name = name;
     this.address = address;
     this.phone = phone;
     this.course = course;
   }
   getInfo() {
     return "Ime: " + this.name + "\n" +
       "Adresa: " + this.address + "\n" +
       "Telefon: " + this.phone + "\n" +
       "Kurs: " + this.course;
   }
 };

 var text = `
Ebonie 
7175 Muland Street
8343242
Math
Keenan 
2 Elm Lane
832432
History
`;

 var lines = text.trim().split('\n');
 var students = Array.from({
   length: lines.length / 4
 }, (_, i) => i).map(index => index * 4).map(index => new Student(lines[index], lines[index + 1], lines[index + 2], lines[index + 3]));
 
 students.forEach(element => console.log(element.getInfo()));
```

Comment: Works perfect :)

Comment: Glad I could help